# NSUserDefaults with UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, uisegmentedcontrol, ios-simulator

I have three UISegmented controls (In a utility application), each of which store their selected segments in UserDefaults when the values is changed. When the settings pane is loaded (the side with the three segmented controls), I access NSUserDefaults to highlight the current settings. For whatever reason, two of them work perfectly as desired, but one seems to randomly fluctuate when the user moves from settings pane to the mainview and back to the settings pane......

This is used to set the selected segment on flip to settings pane:

```
int setting2 = [defaults integerForKey:SegmentKey];
if(setting2 == 0)
{ NSLog(@"selected 0"); segmentedControlC.selectedSegmentIndex = 0; }
else
{ NSLog(@"selected 1"); segmentedControlC.selectedSegmentIndex = 1; }
```

This is used to assign a value to the key "SegmentKey" when the user makes a change to the selectedSegmentIndex

```
[defaults setInteger:segmentedControlC.selectedSegmentIndex forKey:SegmentKey];
```

Yet, for some reason, when I (in the simulator) press the "0" index, flip back to the main view, then return, segment one is highlighted....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you use a unique key dor each integer in NSUserDefaults. And be sure that you `synchronize` NSUserDefaults after you set the integer. 
Also this is faster for loading your keys:

```
segmentedControlC.selectedSegmentIndex = [defaults integerForKey:key];
```

Comment: Alright. By changing my assignments to the way you just described above, that fixed the problem. Kind of. Now, instead of randomly choosing a segment, NSLog is telling my that somewhere between the user pressing the 'info' button to go to the flipside view and the segments being set, the SegmentKey is being assigned the value -1, so neither segment is being selected! How is that possible?

Comment: try to save the integer immediately when you press any segment. Add a target for your segment in viewDidLoad to self with id of @selector(save) for event UIControlEventCalueChanged. and then add a void method with the name of the selector ('save' in this case) and in the void method save the int. Save it using `int idk = yoursegmentedctrl.selectedSegmentIndex;` `[defaults setInteger:idk forKey:@"yourKey"];` That should do it!

Comment: That is exactly what I did for all three. The strange thing is that it works for two of them, but not for one of them. The two that work do exactly that, but for the other one it somehow gets assigned the value of -1 sometime after the flipside view is loaded

Comment: OK try to compare the non working code with the working. Compare it really closely and see if there are any differences

Comment: But the problem is not assigning the selectedSegment to the key, or reading the previously pressed segment to re-highlight the segment when the user returns to the settings pane- these things work. The problem is somehow the value -1 is being assigned to this segmentkey, but not the others. Is this an error code kind of thing?

Comment: I fixed it. I have no idea why this worked, but it did. In my 'setSelectedSegments' method that I call every time the flipside view is called, I had three method calls in a row to set the correct segments. The problem-child was last. I made it the first one set, and all of a sudden it worked. I figured this out because I put NSLogs that would tell me what the value of the segmentkey was every step of the way, and somehow, when the first segment was set, the value was 0, but by the time the problem-segment was set, it had turned to -1. By bumping it up, the problem was solved. Somehow..........

Comment: Ok, good for you! Can you please accdpt and vote up the answer, as I really did help you? thank you